# 2d array flip vertical

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I cannot get my program to flip a ppm image vertically.  As of now my function only spits out the exact image that way inputted. I have this function that executes the flipping...or it suppose to.  Then I have a function immediately following that calls for the image to be read, then flipped, then written out again.  I know that function is okay because I've tested it.  Any ideas of what to do?

```
void ppmFlipVertical(int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS], int numRows, int numCols)
{
int temp, N,L,c;
N=3*numRows;
L=3*numCols;
c=0;

    for(int r=0; r<(N/2); r++)
    {
        temp=image[r][c];
        image[r][c] = image[N-r][c]; 
        temp=image[N-r][c];
    }



}
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying numRows with 3?

Comment: You might start by fixing the last line in your for loop from `temp=image[N-r][c];` to `image[N-r][c] = temp;`

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
//void ppmFlipVertical(int image[][], int maxRows, int MaxColumn)
void ppmFlipVertical(int (&image)[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS])
{
    for (int r = 0; r < (MAXROWS/2); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c != MAXCOLUMNS; ++c)
        {
             std::swap(image[r][c], image[MAXROWS - 1 - r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Your prototype is misleading as parameter `int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]` is equivalent to `int image[][]`.

You may use `std::swap` to swap two values.

The last valid index for row is `MAXROWS -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it flips all the elements methodically.
The only problem is i'm not sure how your image is stored so this is for flipping single cells/items.
I'm sure you could easily extrapolate this item flipper for multiple items at a time.

```
void ppmFlipVertical(int image[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS], int numRows, int numCols)
{
    int tempTop, tempBottom, c;
    for( c = 0; c < numCols; c++ ) //Heh c++
    {
        int r, rMax;
        rMax = numRows / 2;
        for( r = 0; r < rMax; r ++ )
        {
            tempTop=image[r][c];
            tempBottom=image[numRows-r][c];

            image[r][c] = tempBottom; 
            image[numRows-r][c] = tempTop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but only for, what looks like, a few columns on the left side.  The rest of the image is the same.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: if for each 'column'(pixel) there are actually 3 columns (rgb) then try passing "c < 3 * numCols" in the c for loop